# Modern language IDE similar to QBasic?

Tags: ide

I'm trying to find a modern environment similar to what I found great about QBasic but making up for the flaws. The purpose of this is to code with my 6 year old son.

I'm looking for an IDE that uses a modern language, has the ability to draw graphics and play audio, and doesn't force the User to jump around much between coding and running their application.

In QBasic you had basically two modes: Edit and Run. There were no third party libraries required for creating graphics or generating Audio tones (that I remember). You never had more than one "window" opened at a time.

Is there a modern day equivalent IDE which uses a modern language that provides what I'm looking for?

I don't want him to have to jump around between various windows, try to wrap his mind around window toolkits, understand the command line, or use OOP just to get started. My end goal is to create simple graphical games with him -- not printing text out to the console.

(Preferably cross platform or useable on Mac OSX since that's what we have at the house. Preferably Python based since that's my language of choice.)

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QBasic is a great option.  You can purchase an old PC from a thrift store and run QBasic on it.  There is the option of [QB64](http://www.qb64.net/) which can run on both Mac and Windows.  Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest QB64, almost 100% compatible with QBasic/QuickBasic but runs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try [Small Basic](http://smallbasic.com/), it aimed to recreate the ease-of-use and educational purposes of the old BASIC languages build into home computers from the 1980s

The Small Basic project was initiated following this article on Salon:
[Why Johnny can’t code (David Brin, 2006)](http://www.salon.com/2006/09/14/basic_2/)